# Why doesnt my Expression Tree recognize my custom method?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I recently posted a question on [how to write customized expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287111/can-you-teach-entity-framework-to-recognize-an-expression/21289676#21289676) (though I didn't realize that was what I was asking at the time). Now I am trying to use the answer provided by Scott Chamberlain to create another generic method.

I am using Entity Framework and have several Entities that can be filtered by something like a "Name" property. It isn't always called Name, but that is basically what it is.

The actual filter method is more complex than a simple contains or starts with. It is more like a Starts With, then append any records with a name containing the search text to the end of the list.

Since there are so many Entities that will need to perform this filter, I would like to be able to create an Extension Method that applies that filter to the pre-compiled query.

I would like to be able to call

```
    someQuery.ContainsName(x => x.Name, filter.Name);
```

I have an extension method that looks like this

```
      public static IQueryable<T> ContainsName<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string matchingName)
    {
        var name = Expression.Constant(matchingName);

        var selectorBody = selector.Body;
        var propertyName = (selectorBody as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
        var propExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), propertyName);

        var selectorParameters = selector.Parameters;

        Expression check = Expression.Call(typeof(GenericNameFilter).GetMethod("IsMatch"), propExpression, name);

        var lambada = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(check, selectorParameters);

        return query.Where(lambada) 
    }
```

IsMatch just takes in 2 strings and returns a bool. This isn't really the end game for the method, but I wanted to be able to get a simple version of IsMatch working, then I would expand on it.

When I call ToList on the result, I get an exception.

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

From the searches I have done I believe what I am trying to do is possible, I am just doing it incorrectly. Is it in the way I am setting up my expression tree? Is it the IsMatch method? Is everything about this wrong?

Comment: No; this is not possible.  How is EF supposed to know how to convert `IsMatch(...)` into SQL?

Comment: What confuses me is that there is a method called "Call", which seems like it is designed to execute methods like that. The example on MSDN looks like 

Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
                Expression.Constant("sample string"), typeof(String).GetMethod("ToUpper", new Type[] { }));

Is it only native methods that work with Call?

Comment: Expression trees are not unique to EF; they support more functionality than EF does.  But `Call()` is also used for `EntityFunctions`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gist of the problem is that you can't write query operations that result in code being run, because the database obviously cannot run your C# code on its data.

Your extension method adds a lambda call to the query pipeline; you intend it to be resolved to some overload of the `IsMatch` method. However, that means nothing to the database so the EF query provider tells you that it cannot translate what you wrote to SQL. Unfortunately there is no way around that.

The same code would run just fine on LINQ to objects because in that scenario the compiler can of course arrange for your method to be called.

Comment: I initially thought that was the case, but when looking at the Expression.Call method, it seems like you would be able to. It takes some combination of MethodInfo and 1 or Property Expressions. Is it limited to native methods?

Comment: @bsayegh: You would be able to what? Translate your method's code to SQL?

Comment: Well, maybe not translate in to Sql. I am pretty confused by how this works. I figured .net would execute the query, then apply my code after executing the sql.

Comment: @bsayegh: If that's what you want then you have to work with `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>` and ditch the expression trees entirely.

Comment: I tried using IEnumerable before but there was a snag. It seemed like I needed implement an interface or base class that had a Name property so that my method would know what property to query off of. While I can apply it to each Entity, the classes would get regenerated every time I update the database mapping. 

Is there a way to accomplish my goal without using an interface?

Comment: @bsayegh: You should probably ask a new question and post the relevant code, otherwise there will be just too much guessing going on.